# How can I print out an int* which I am accessing using [rows][cols] indexing?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I get a compile error on printf("%d ", arr[rows][cols]); line with compiler error:

```
//error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

I want the convenience of rows by cols.  What is the easiest way to access?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_matrix(int* arr, int numrows, int numcolumns) {
    for(int rows = 0; rows < numrows; ++rows) {
        for(int cols = 0; cols < numcolumns; ++cols)
            printf("%d ", arr[rows][cols]);   //error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    const int rows = 3;
    const int cols = 2;
    int arr[rows][cols] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };

    int* p = &arr[0][0];

    print_matrix(p, rows, cols);

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

For a bit of completeness, I thought about H2C03's comment and I should have thought it through a bit more thoroughly.  The following is another way to achieve the same thing and is simpler in that the function takes a simple pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_matrix(int* arr, int rows, int cols) {
    int row, col;
    for( row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        for(col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
            printf("%d ", *(arr + row * cols + col));  

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_transpose(int* arr, int rows, int cols) {
    int row, col;
    for(row = 0; row < cols; ++row) {
        for( col = 0; col < rows; ++col)
            printf("%d ", *(arr + col * cols + row));  

        printf("\n");
    } 
}

int main() {

    const int rows = 3;
    const int cols = 2;
    int arr[3][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };
    int* p = arr;
    printf("matrix:\n");
    print_matrix(p, rows, cols);
    printf("transposed:\n");
    print_transpose(p, rows, cols);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr[rows * numcolumns + cols]`... did you even **think** about what `arr[rows][cols]` means?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks a minimal knowledge of the language used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the pointer as a two-dimensional array pointer:

```
void print_matrix(size_t numrows, size_t numcolumns, int (* arr)[numcolumns]);
```

And pass as

```
print_matrix(rows, cols, arr);
```

Comment: No, he doesn't need to.

Comment: @H2CO3 he doesn't need to, but it's the easiest and most convenient way to do.

Comment: Obviously, OP wants to decode the row major format manually. I bet this is a sort of exercise.

Comment: @H2CO3 I cite the OP: I want the convenience of rows by cols.

Comment: Who is downvoting this answer or trying to delete it? I tend to have the same interpretation of the question: "how to get the 2D structure of the matrix passed into the function?"

Answer (score 1):

Since `p` is a pointer to the first element of `arr` i.e. `p = &arr[0][0]`, if we dereference `p` we get the value at `&arr[0][0]`. Now `arr` is the duplicate of pointer `p` in function `print_matrix` and hence if we dereference `arr`, we get the value at `arr[0][0]`. i.e. `*arr` gives `arr[0][0]` but `arr[rows][cols]` evaluates to `*(*(arr+rows) + cols)`. This is a problem because `*(arr+rows)` gives a value which CANNOT be dereferenced again. I suggest a simpler solution:

```
void print_matrix(int* arr, int numrows, int numcolumns) 
{
int totalelements = numrows * numcolumns, i ; 

    for(i = 0; i < totalelements; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%d\t ", arr[i]);  
        if((i+1) % numcolumns == 0)
          printf("\n");
    }
```

}